# How can I tell if an IQueryable is an IOrderedQueryable?

Tags: c#, linq

I have an IQueryable. I have not called OrderBy on it or otherwise done anything with it.

If I do:

```
// for some reason, isItOrdered is always true
var isItOrdered = myQueryable is IOrderedQueryable<T>
```

Why is this always true? (It seems like it shouldn't be.) And, more importantly, how can I tell if an IQueryable already has been ordered? (i.e. is truly an IOrderedQueryable)

I would like to be able to do something like:

```
if (myQueryable is IOrderedQueryable<T>)
  myQueryable = myQueryable.ThenBy(...);
else
  myQueryable = myQueryable.OrderBy(...);
```

Comment: you should see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36923850/how-to-know-if-orderby-was-applied-to-query

Answer (score 15):

You haven't shown what's creating your queryable to start with, but perhaps it's naturally ordered in some way?

What you've got *does* check whether it's really an `IOrderedQueryable<T>` - I suspect that it's just that your query provider *always* provides an ordered queryable, even if the order isn't obvious.

EDIT: Okay, something else you might try:

```
if (typeof(IOrderedQueryable<T>).IsAssignableFrom(myQueryable.Expression.Type))
```

... or in general, print out `myQueryable.Expression.Type` and see what it looks like.

Comment: The problem is that I get a nasty exception when I try to to the ThenBy. It goes something like this: Expression of type System.Linq.IQueryable<T> cannot be used for parameter of type IOrderedQueryable<T> of method IOrderedQueryable<T> ThenBy ....

Comment: The problem with Entity Framework is that EF `DbSet<T>` inherits from `DbQuery<T>` which itself implements `IOrderedQueryable<T>`! So your statement always returns `true` if `myQueryable` is an EF query but not sorted at all.

Comment: @MassoodKhaari: Ick - that's horrible :( My answer still answers the question as asked of course - it just means that it's not a *useful* question to be asking...

Comment: But I think this is the exact source of the questioned problem. He has an `IQueryable` object with no call to `OrderBy` at all. But the statement `myQueryable is IOrderedQueryable<T>` always returns `true`. The implication is that one can create an `IOrderedQueryable<T>` object which is indeed unsorted. And the other implication is that EF exactly do such a weird thing. (It internally checks the query object expression instead to detect if it is ordered through calls to `OrderBy` or `OrderByDescending`.)

Comment: @JonSkeet Your solution using IsAssignableFrom(myQueryable.Expression.Type)) worked for me, btw.  Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately `IsAssignableFrom` is not available in dnxcore50.

The fact that we can't call ThenBy on an IOrderedQueryable<T> seems like a bug to me. This seems to be the only work around.

    `if (query.Expression.Type == typeof(IOrderedQueryable<T>))`

Comment: @Dave: Are you sure this isn't just a matter of using `TypeInfo`? That tends to be the way of things with reflection in dnxcore...

Comment: It helps me well, but was still not enough for all my cases. When the EF6 `DbSet` was only touched by `Include` (no `Where`), testing `IsAssignableFrom` is still returning `true` on unsorted queries. To fix that, I had to change the test to: `typeof(IOrderedQueryable<T>).IsAssignableFrom(query.Expression.Type) && query.Expression.Type != typeof(System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery<T>)`. Even uglier.

Answer (score 8):

This seems to work

```
if (query.Expression.Type == typeof(IOrderedQueryable<T>))
    myQueryable = myQueryable.ThenBy(...);
else
    myQueryable = myQueryable.OrderBy(...);
```

Answer (score 1):

Some `IQueryable` implementations reuse the same class for `IOrderedQueryable<T>`.

There isn't much of a point in checking if it's really already ordered unless you know **how** it's ordered, otherwise you might order by the exact same property when you call `ThenBy()`.

Also, you can't call `Queryable.ThenBy()` on `myQueryable` if it's a reference to `IQueryable`—you have to cast it first:

```
if (myQueryable is IOrderedQueryable<T>)
   myQueryable = ((IOrderedQueryable<T>) myQueryable).ThenBy(...);
```

Comment: True. But in my case it isn't a problem if I have a redundant ordering. I get a crazy exception as I mentioned in the comment to Jon Skeet.

Comment: Yes---I do cast it first. I still get the exception.

Comment: @MarkCidade I'm having this same issue, using the code you posted above.

@Pedro Are you using Entity Framework 7 by any chance?

`var myQueryable  = context.Table.Select(x => x);` or `var myQueryable  = from x in context.Table select x` both return IOrderedQueryable<T>, but calling ThenBy() throws an ArgumentException at runtime.

Comment: The exception says: Additional information: Expression of type 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[Models.Table]' cannot be used for parameter of type 'System.Linq.IOrderedQueryable`1[Models.Table]' of method 'System.Linq.IOrderedQueryable`1[Models.Table] ThenBy[Table,String](System.Linq.IOrderedQueryable`1[Models.Table], System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`2[Models.Table,System.String]])'