# Writing a function to add sort filters

Tags: vb.net, linq, entity-framework-4, func

We are trying to build a smart sort of columns straight from a database table. This is becoming a if -else chain nightmare of determining whether to add `OrderBy`, `OrderByDescending`, `ThenBy`, or `ThenByDescending` to the `IOrderedQueryable(Of EntityType)` object.

I'd like to make a function that would take the `IQueryable(Of EntityType)` object, a `Boolean` that determines whether the column to sort by is the first one or not, another `Boolean` to determine whether the sort is to be ascending or descending, and the lambda function that returns the column to sort by (the type of which varies throughout the columns that we need to sort by), and return an `IOrderedQueryable(Of EntityType)` object with the appropriate filter added.

How do I do this?

Comment: Do you mean a function which will add `.OrderBy()` or `.ThenBy()` to an `IQueryable`? If you look at this SO question's answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8507746/determine-whether-an-iqueryablet-has-been-ordered-or-not I think it is not possible unless you track the state of the `IQueryable`yourself. Maybe you can make a custom `IQueryable` class which keeps a list of any sorting which has been performed on it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamic LINQ OrderBy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41244/dynamic-linq-orderby)

Comment: [this article](http://www.thereforesystems.com/dynamic-sort-with-linq-to-sql/) helps show the way.