# Check if a Linq IQueryable has an order by applied

Tags: c#, linq, expression-trees

Is there any way to find out if an IQueryable object has an OrderBy applied within its expression tree?

The scenario I have is that a grid control has paging enabled, and sorting per column. However there is not a sort applied by default, so in this case Linq to SQL does a horribly huge select for the row count, so in all scenarios I need to provide an order by, however I should only apply a default order by primary key if no other order has been specified.

So is this possible?

Comment: Only way I can think of is to do an orderby and see if the order is the same, or set a boolean when ordering, edit a shorter way may be to compare elements to see if theyre ordered

Comment: In what way would the orderby(id) help the huge select?

Comment: @usr Linq2Sql will use ALL COLUMNS in its `SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY <every-single-column-)` if there is no explicit orderby criteria applied to the underlying query. So for example I have a query which takes 30 seconds to run on the DB without an order by, but takes less than 1 second with an orderby applied. So if I can explicitly set the primary key as the orderby if there is no automatic orderby set from the sort expression of the grid, then I can shave off a ton of time wasted because of the badly composed Linq query.

Comment: Can you not use `typeof(IOrderedQueryable<T>).IsAssignableFrom(myQueryable.Expression.Type)` as suggested in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5071426/how-can-i-tell-if-an-iqueryable-is-an-iorderedqueryable ?

Comment: @Grofit you should see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36923850/how-to-know-if-orderby-was-applied-to-query

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can find out by inspecting the expression tree of the query using a custom `ExpressionVisitor` or any recursive traversal mechanism of your choice.

I sense that your code is not well designed. You probably should just store that fact that ordering has been applied somewhere as a `bool`. Maybe the information flow of your app needs to be rearchitected.

With this inspection approach you are recovering this information in a hackish way.

Comment: Oh yes there is no doubt in my mind this is badly designed code, unfortunately as I am constrained by my clients technology choices from the prehistoric times I am limited in my choices to solve the underlying problem, and the grid control *can* have a default sort applied, but someone may turn the sorting off anyway which would cause problems so working on the underlying query (as it goes through a common interface for processing before being used by the grid).