# How to know if OrderBy was applied to query?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I need to know if an OrderBy was applied to a Linq query before applying an .Skip or .Take. I have no control of the received query and if an OrderBy was applied I need to maintain this one, in any other case I should OrderBy(t=>true). I have tried the following:

```
    DataContext db;
    var query = db.Orders;

    var wasOrderByApplied = typeof(IOrderedQueryable<Order>).IsAssignableFrom(query.AsQueryable().Expression.Type);
    var wasOrderByApplied2 = query.AsQueryable().Expression.Type == typeof(System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery<Order>);
    var wasOrderByApplied3 = typeof(IOrderedQueryable<Order>) == query.AsQueryable().Expression.Type;

    var query2 = db.Orders.OrderBy(o => o.CreationDate);

    var wasOrderByApplied4 = typeof(IOrderedQueryable<Order>).IsAssignableFrom(query2.AsQueryable().Expression.Type);
    var wasOrderByApplied5 = query2.AsQueryable().Expression.Type == typeof(System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery<Order>);
    var wasOrderByApplied6 = typeof(IOrderedQueryable<Order>) == query2.AsQueryable().Expression.Type;

    var query3 = db.Orders.OrderBy(o => o.CreationDate).Where(o => o.Id > 4);

    var wasOrderByApplied7 = typeof(IOrderedQueryable<Order>).IsAssignableFrom(query3.AsQueryable().Expression.Type);
    var wasOrderByApplied8 = query3.AsQueryable().Expression.Type == typeof(System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery<Order>);
    var wasOrderByApplied9 = typeof(IOrderedQueryable<Order>) == query3.AsQueryable().Expression.Type;
```

The results where:

```
wasOrderByApplied = true;
wasOrderByApplied2 = true;
wasOrderByApplied3 = false;

wasOrderByApplied4 = true;
wasOrderByApplied5 = false;
wasOrderByApplied6 = true;
```

With the last results it seems that the third question asked to each query is the one that is correct, but then I did the third query (query3) and the results where:

```
wasOrderByApplied7 = false;
wasOrderByApplied8 = false;
wasOrderByApplied9 = false;
```

When I add a Where after the OrderBy the question result is **false** where it should be **true**.

Is there a better way to know if an OrderBy was applied to the query?

Comment: Why don't you just change the method overload to only take in an IOrderedQueryable and have another overload that takes in the IQueryable and calls orderby(x => true) and then calls the ordered overload

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is one possible solution that came to my mind:

Create an expression visitor that checks whether the expression invokes the `OrderBy`, or the `OrderByDescending` method like this:

```
public class MyVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    public bool HasOrderBy { get; private set; }

    protected override Expression VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression node)
    {
        if (node.Method.DeclaringType == typeof (Queryable) &&
            (node.Method.Name == "OrderBy" || node.Method.Name == "OrderByDescending"))
            HasOrderBy = true;

        return base.VisitMethodCall(node);
    }
}
```

Here is how you can use it:

```
MyVisitor visitor = new MyVisitor();

visitor.Visit(query.Expression);

if (visitor.HasOrderBy)
{
    //..
}
else
{
    //..
}
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: With C# 6 I'd recommend using `nameof(Queryable.OrderBy)`, etc. to get rid of the magic strings.

Comment: @KirkWoll, I agree. However, I prefer to use older syntax here (on stackoverflow) since I cannot assume OP or other readers are using C#6.

Comment: @KirkWoll, right. I think it is safe to use C# 4 or 5.

Comment: Sure, fair enough.

Comment: @KirkWoll In my very special case I can't use C# 6 because it will be used in different environments where I can't ensure it will be available.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to know what. It is pointless. If you want to `Take` or `Skip` some elements you need to order them just before that. Consider following

```
class Animal
{
    public int Weight { get; set; }
    public int NumberOfLegs { get; set; }
}

...

public IEnumerable<Animal> TakeFive(IEnumerable<Animal> animals)
{
    return animals.Take(5);
}
```

What five animals would you take? Those what have most legs? Or those that weighting more? Or those that weighting less? You don't know. But if you change code like so

```
public IEnumerable<Animal> TakeFive(IEnumerable<Animal> animals)
{
    return animals.OrderBy(_ => .Weight).Take(5);
}
```

It's starting to make some sense.

You can apply the same not only to `IEnumerable` but to `IQueryable` also. There is no need to know if sequence is ordered if you don't know what order is.

Comment: I concur with this - if the IList is already in the correct order, OrderBy will only cost a single pass of the list.

Comment: In my case, I don't need to know the order, I just need to know if it was ordered. The order is placed by the client of my library.

Comment: I do not have a list, I have a DataContext witch generates a hit to a database.

Comment: And if it is not ordered what order you will apply? You should expect either ordered result from the client or unordered. I believe there is always a way to refactor this.

Comment: `OrderBy(t => true)` won't give you order that differs from those that was passed to method. This way you can just `Take` or `Skip` needed number of elements and don't check for order. It would be the same.

Comment: Imagine that you have a library that shows items in a table. It is a generic table, where you don't know the type of the items. The clients are the ones that know how to order them, not my library. How can I order something that I don't know its type?

Comment: @MaximKosov OrderBy is needed to use Take or Skip in Entity Framework, if not used, an Exception will be thrown.

Comment: I see. I'm sure there is a way to refactor this so you _always_ know if user applied any sorting or not.